# async/await with HTTP method

Tags: asynchronous

If you use a fetch method for HTTP communication in a code that does not consider asynchronous processing at all, all functions (even the main function, to take it to the extreme) that include a fetch method, even if only a little, will need to use async/await (asynchronous processing) Is it necessary to think about
Or can we limit the scope of asynchronous processing?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to go [`async` all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way).

If you use a hexagonal / ports-and-adapters architecture, you can (sometimes) extract the I/O operations into "ports" and keep your core business logic synchronous. But the composition of the synchronous business logic and the asynchronous ports is asynchronous, so your main entry points are almost always asynchronous.